# jQuery Remove tr after ajax success

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to remove table row after successful ajax call, but it is not working. No errors in firebug, it deletes the row on the back-end PHP, just doesnt remove the tr. Here is my code:

```
function closelead(rowid){
            var rowid = rowid;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/close.php",
                data: "rowid="+ rowid,

                success: function(html){

                    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                }
            });

            }
```

and the html:

```
<table  id="companytable">
        <tr id="top"><th>Business Name</th><th>Phone</th><th>Carrier</th><th>X-Date</th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>
        <?php
        $query =   "SELECT * FROM leads WHERE user = '$user' ORDER BY wccompcode";
         $selectlead = mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
         while($leadlist = mysql_fetch_array($selectlead)){
            $compcode = $leadlist['wccompcode'];
            $compcode = sprintf("%03s", $compcode);
            $selcomp = mysql_query("SELECT carname FROM carrierlist WHERE carcode = '$compcode'")or die(mysql_error());

            while($carrier = mysql_fetch_array($selcomp)){
                $carrier1 = $carrier['carname'];
            }
            ?>
            <tr id="<?php echo $leadlist['ID'];?>"><td id="busname"><?php echo $leadlist['busname'];?></td><td><?php echo $leadlist['phone'];?></td><td><?php echo $carrier1;?></td><td><?php echo date("m/d/Y",strtotime($leadlist['wcxdate']));?></td><td><input type="button" value="Call Back" class="searchbutton" /></td><td><input type="button" onclick="closelead(<?php echo $leadlist['ID'];?>)" value="Close" class="searchbutton" /></td><td><input type="button" value="Soft Quote" class="searchbutton" /></td></tr>
            <?
         }
        ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: Try $('#'+rowid).hide(); instead of $(this).closest('tr').remove();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
function closelead(rowid){
    var rowid = rowid;                
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/close.php",
        data: "rowid="+ rowid,                    
        success: function(html){                        
            $('#'+rowid).remove();
        }
    });                 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function closelead(rowid){
            var rowid = rowid;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax/close.php",
                data: "rowid="+ rowid,

                success: function(html){

                    $('#'+rowid).closest('tr').remove();
                }
            });

            }
```